# Running masonry on jekyll

Tags: ruby, yaml, jekyll

I just wanted to launch masonry on jekyll, basic setup as on github https://github.com/desandro/masonry

Here is a _config.yml file:

```
nname: jQueryM
auto: false
permalink: /:categories/:title.html
pygments: true
masonry_js: jquery.masonry.min.js
jquery_js: js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
exclude: [ minify.sh, notes.mdown ]
```

But keep getting this error:

```
localhost:masonry macin$ jekyll --server
Configuration from /Users/macin/Sites/masonry/_config.yml
Building site: /Users/macin/Sites/masonry -> /Users/macin/Sites/masonry/_site
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 10 column 14 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:33:in `read_yaml'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/post.rb:39:in `initialize'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:163:in `new'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:163:in `block in read_posts'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:161:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:161:in `read_posts'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:128:in `read_directories'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:98:in `read'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:38:in `process'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/jekyll:250:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/jekyll:19:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/jekyll:19:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong here. I checked _config.yml for any tabs as sugested in other posts but still not working. 
Thank you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably in this line:

```
permalink: /:categories/:title.html
```

Colons have a meaning (separating keys from values) in YAML, so using them in a value can get messy. Surround the value in double quotes:

```
permalink: "/:categories/:title.html"
```